# Reading a WMF header with WINAPI

Tags: winapi, wmf, .emf

I can't seem to find anywhere how I can read the header of a .wmf file with C/C++ and the Win32 API.

Can anyone give me some pointers and/or an example?

I have a C++ application that must be able to recognize whether some chunk of binary data is a WMF picture. Next on the list is .emf and I predict that I will have the same problem with it.

The MSDN article does not contain any function reference or whatever:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250370(v=PROT.10).aspx

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about [GetEnhMetaFileHeader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144883%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?